# Keeping one column fixed and transposition other columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-manipulation

I have a table like so:

| Unique # | Cost | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12352 | 2165.5 | 2022-01-01 12:20 |
| 35256 | 2360.5 | 2022-01-01 12:20 |
| 12352 | 3254.0 | 2022-01-04 18:20 |
| 35256 | 3460.5 | 2022-01-04 18:20 |

But, I am trying to get columns as the date name (something like a pivot table):

| Unique # | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-04 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12352 | 2165.5 | 3254.0 | -- |
| 35256 | 2360.5 | 3460.5 | -- |

I understand this is fairly easy to do in Pandas using `groupby` and `unstack`, but I am trying to achieve this in SQL.

Comment: Which product are you using? SQL Server has a command for this, MySQL does not. Please add the relevant tag

Comment: In Snowflake SQL

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
WITH CTE AS(
select 12352 unique_id, 2165.5 cost ,'2022-01-01 12:20'::TIMESTAMP DATES, DATES::DATE DAY_AGG UNION ALL
select 35256 unique_id, 2360.5 cost ,'2022-01-01 12:20'::TIMESTAMP DATES, DATES::DATE DAY_AGG UNION ALL
select 12352 unique_id, 3254.0 cost ,'2022-01-04 18:20'::TIMESTAMP DATES, DATES::DATE DAY_AGG UNION ALL
select 35256 unique_id, 3460.5 cost ,'2022-01-04 18:20'::TIMESTAMP DATES, DATES::DATE DAY_AGG)

,CTE2 AS(SELECT UNIQUE_ID, DAY_AGG, SUM(COST) DAILY_COST 
FROM CTE GROUP BY UNIQUE_ID, DAY_AGG )

SELECT * FROM CTE2
   PIVOT(SUM(DAILY_COST)FOR DAY_AGG IN('2022-01-01','2022-01-04')) ;
```